# Regex to find first extension in OpenFileDialog filter string

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, winforms, .net-2.0

I want to find the first extension in list of exentions in `OpenFileDialog` file filter string.

Consider the below example -

`Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF`

`Text files (*.txt)|*.txt`

For first case - Now if the user tries to save a file without extension then by default I want to append the `.BMP` extension to the filename.

For second case - Now if the user tries to save a file without extension then by default I want to append the `.txt` extension to the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use regex to split the string, simply use the Split function as suggested by SysDragon - there is no earthly reason why you wouldn't do this. Once you have the second part of the original string then this regex will get you `BMP` from `*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF` as the one and only match.

```
^\|\*\.(\w{1,4});
```

Simply put, this says the following:

- **^**    start at the beginning of the string
- **\|**   find  a pipe character (the \ delimits it because this is the equivalent of OR in regex)
- **\*** Find a single * character (again, delimited because * means 'zero or more repetitions' in a regex)
- **\.** Find a single period (delimited because this means 'any character' normally)
- **(\w{1,4})** Find at least 1 and up to 4 alphanumeric characters. This is a capturing group so you can obtain this from the match object.
- **;** Find a semi colon

I have arbitrarily chosen 1-4 alphanumeric characters but you can adjust this to suit your needs, for instance `{3}` would mean 'find exactly three', `[A-Za-z]{1,3}` would mean 'find at least one and up to three matches from the letters A-Z and a-z'.

Since you only wanted the first extension this will do what you want but you could always amend the pattern to give you all the extensions as a match collection. In fact that regex is even simpler (but then why return *n* matches when 1 will do?) and I'll levae that for you as a learning exercise :-)

Comment: A very comprehensive answer Steve. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have a property on `SaveFileDialog` to append the extension to no-extension name files, check the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.defaultext.aspx) about it.

```
myOpenFile.DefaultExt = ".bmp"
```

Anyway, you can get the first extension of a filter doing something like this:

```
Dim sExt As String = sFilter.Split("|"c)(1).Split(";"c)(0)
```

Then you need to clear the `*` in the way you want, for example:

- `sExt = sExt.Replace("*","")`
- `sExt = sExt.SubString(sExt.LastIndexOf("."c))`

I recommend you the second example as it will get the extension even if the filter has no `*` and has more specific filename.

Comment: I'm writing a custom `OpenFileDialog` where I need to process the same.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. You mean that you want to define the `DefaultExt` property in your custom `OpenFileDailog` and that's why you want to take the first extension of the filter? I don't think `DefaultExt` works in that way. Anyway, did the second part worked for you?

Comment: I'm writing a custom `OpenFileDialog` of my own, where I have `Filter` property as there is in the original `OpenFileDialog` and the users of my `CustomOpenFileDialog` class can populate the `Filter` property. Now considering your answer if the filter string `Text files (*.txt)|*.txt` then there are no `;(Semi-Colon)` characters in which case the split won't work. I was looking for a regex solution.

Comment: Of course it works, did you tried at least? It takes the first extension of any filter. Try it yourself

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, you want to automatically populate an equivalent of `DefaultExt` in your custom dialog when the user enters the filter list to save them having to do it manually, right? And you want a regex? If so then the first thing to do is read a decent primer on regular expressions such as http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and then download Expresso (it's completely free) and learn to build one yourself. It's really not very hard and this should be thought of as a learning opportunity for you.

Comment: @StevePettifer I tried every way I knew in Expresso but couldn't find a decent one that works. A little help would be very appreciated.

Comment: @SysDragon Found something with regex. I've posted it as an answer. Please feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I used two different regex to accomplish the task. The first regex I used is

```
(?<Name>[^|]*)\|(?<Extension>[^|]*)\|?
```

to break the expression of name and file

```
Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF
```

into two parts

- `Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)`
- `*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF`

Then I used the regex

```
\*\.(?<Name>[^;]\w*)
```

on the `Entension` part of the first regex group to get more groups like `BMP`,`JPG`,`GIF` and then taking the first group match occurring. I would really thank [Steve Pettifer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60602/steve-pettifer) for his encouragement to use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

Comment: Expresso has rescued me on many, many occasions. And seeing as you've made a good effort, I'll help you along a bit more with an answer and suggestion.

Comment: Its simplier if you use the split without regex as I posted in my answer